# Help with South African 90 Day Visitor visa

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, legal, uk-citizens, south-africa

I am a brit visiting family and friends in South Africa with my duel brit/south african GF, I have already been granted a 90 day Visitor visa which expires the end of July, unfortunately i haven't been able to do the rest of my itinerary yet and am wanting to leave South Africa and return until October (which is when the return flight to England is booked) I have read lots of conflicting information about going on holiday to Botswana or similar surrounding countries for a few weeks or having to return home to then come back again to obtain the new 90 day visa. I have also called the Embassy who informed me that you have to leave 90 days between each 90 day visa is granted which is crazy surely? She also wasn't really listening and never asked me my country of origin. Any help would  be appreciated as I am eager to return for another adventure with my GF. I do not intend on overstaying as we both live in England etc and have just taken a year travelling break both visiting Australia and now visiting South Africa. Thanks